# SimpleInjector `Controller is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable` Error for ApiController

Tags: c#, .net-core, simple-injector

So, this error has been giving other users troubles for years as much as I could see on my research. **Their** suggested **solutions** on the other hand, **don't work** for **my project** somehow.

So, my startup class is;

```
public class Startup
{
    private Container container = new Container();
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(
            Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json").Build();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
              "CorsPolicy",
              builder => builder.WithOrigins(new[] { "http://localhost" })
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials()
            );
        });

        services.AddControllers(); // ERR 1

        services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options => /// ERR 2
        {
            options
                .AddAspNetCore()
                .AddControllerActivation();
        });
        services.AddCors();

        InitializeContainer();
    }

    private void InitializeContainer()
    {
        // Register services
        ConnectionConfig conf = new ConnectionConfig();
        AppSettings settings = new AppSettings();
        PathConfig path = new PathConfig();
        Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(settings);
        Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionConfig").Bind(conf);
        Configuration.GetSection("PathConfig").Bind(path);
        container.RegisterInstance<ConnectionConfig>(conf);
        container.RegisterInstance<PathConfig>(path);
        container.RegisterInstance<AppSettings>(settings);

        new CoreModule().RegisterServices(container);
        new DataModule().RegisterServices(container);
        new ServiceModule().RegisterServices(container);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseCors(
           options => options
           .AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
        );

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseSimpleInjector(container);

        container.Verify(); /// ERR 3
    }
}
```

The error for `ERR 3` is;
[image: Error]

The suggested solutions say, that I should register these controllers with the LifestyleScope of `Scoped` but when I try to do that, it gives error at `ERR 2`.
`ERR 2`:

> A registration for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager is missing from the ASP.NET Core configuration system. This is most likely caused by a missing call to services.AddMvcCore() or services.AddMvc() as part of the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection) method of the Startup class. A call to one of those methods will ensure the registration of the ApplicationPartManager.

```
at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreBuilderMvcCoreExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services, String methodName)
at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreBuilderMvcCoreExtensions.AddControllerActivation(SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreBuilder builder)
at ....Startup.<>c.<ConfigureServices>b__5_1(SimpleInjectorAddOptions options) in C:\Projects\...\Startup.cs:line 48
at SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorServiceCollectionExtensions.AddSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services, Container container, Action`1 setupAction)
at ....Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Projects\...\Startup.cs:line 46
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Invoke>g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Build>b__0(IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at ....Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\...\Program.cs:line 16
```

My issue's root is, my poor intensions on returning `IHttpAction` from the `BaseApiController`. My reasons for that is, to make sure my API's client is always in the knowledge of what's happening in case an error happens. Without returning `InternalServerError` or `Ok()` etc, it's kind of harder for me to explain my error to the client.

This is the `BaseApiController`:

```
// When I use `ControllerBase` here for the inheritance, API works like a charm 
// after getting rid of the `IHttpActionResult` and writing `T` instead.

public class BaseApiController : ApiController 
{
    private readonly LogModule _logModule;

    public BaseApiController(LogModule logModule)
    {
        _logModule = logModule;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult ExecuteAction<T>(Func<BaseResponse<T>> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(func());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var requestScope = Request.GetDependencyScope();
            var logModule = requestScope.GetService(typeof(LogModule)) as LogModule;

            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var description = "API." + this.GetType().Name + "." + stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
            logModule.Error(description, ex);
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a controller I use;

```
[Route("api/foo")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly FooService _fooService;

    public FooController(FooService fooService, LogModule logModule) : base(logModule)
    {
        _fooService = fooService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create_foo")]
    public System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetFoo([FromBody] FooRequest request)
    {
        var baseResponse = ExecuteAction(() =>
        {
            return _fooService.AddFoo(request);
        });
        return baseResponse;
    }
}
```

In conclusion, how can I use SimpleInjector with `ApiController`s?

Comment: Can you show err2 with message and full stack trace? (Please no screen shots)

Comment: Why do you need IDisposable on your controller anyway? This is typically a mess such controller is doing too much. Generally, resource cleanup is something for lower-level services. Can you show a controller that needs disposal?

Comment: @Steven, I edited question with ERR2. I'm simply creating an api via referencing an already built api. And also this api will eventually be used by hundreds at the same time so I guess that would make a difference...

Comment: @Steven I also added a controller I use which inherits the `BaseApiController`

Comment: The exception states: "The registration for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager is missing from the ASP.NET Core configuration system. This is most likely caused by a missing call to services.AddMvcCore() or services.AddMvc() as part of the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection) method of the Startup class. A call to one of those methods will ensure the registration of the ApplicationPartManager." Did you try the advice of this message? If so, what happens?

Comment: So your BaseConteoller implements IDisposable? Why is that?

Comment: When I do what the error says, there's an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Bar.Service.Foo.FooService' while attempting to activate 'Bar.Controllers.FooController'.
`

Comment: My `BaseApiController` has the `System.Web.Http.ApiController` as an inheritance. I'm not really pointing out the `IDisposable` part, it's somewhere I can't control.

Comment: Make sure you call AddMvc or AddMvcCore *before* calling AddSimpleInjector. If you do that, what happens?

Comment: I added the `AddMvc` before the `AddSimpleInjector` and got the above error

Comment: I am confused. You are using `System.Web.Http.ApiController`? There is no `System.Web.Http.ApiController` in ASP.NET Core. System.Web.Http.ApiController is part of ASP.NET (classic) Web API. Are you accidentally mixing things here?

Comment: Probably yes. I couldn't find a way to return HTTP Exceptions in other ways so I chose to do it using `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. And for my future acts, how exactly did you confirm that ASP.NET Core doesn't have the `System.Web.Http.ApiController`?

Comment: Well, that's because for one, System.Web.Http is not an ASP.NET Core namespace, that's for a classic Web API, and two, when pulling in all ASP.NET Core namespaces, there is no reference to System.Web.Http from ASP.NET Core, and neither does `ControllerBase` reference it in any way. You must have pulled in this assembly into your application yourself. I can't predict what other problems might arise, but I've got the feeling that *inheriting* from `ApiController` isn't really the best approach to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To register your Controllers as `Scoped`, you can use the following code:

```cs
// inside ConfigureServices or Startup ctor
this.container.Options.LifestyleSelectionBehavior = new ApiControllersAsScopedBehavior();

// behavior
internal class ApiControllersAsScopedBehavior : ILifestyleSelectionBehavior
{
    public Lifestyle SelectLifestyle(Type implementationType) =>
        typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(implementationType)
            ? Lifestyle.Scoped
            : Lifestyle.Transient;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steven for making things clear for me in the above chat. I cleared the `System.Web.Http` and did an alternative way by using https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/migration/webapi?view=aspnetcore-5.0